# Can Minecraft Java Edition run on Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-7, windows-10

I've been using the original Java Edition on my old Windows 7 PC for years and my family just gave me a new Windows 10 PC for Christmas. Can I keep using my old Java Edition on the new machine or do I have to switch to the Windows 10 Edition of Minecraft? I really don't want to switch...

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be under the impression that a Windows 10 machine is forced to play the Windows 10 edition of the game.  This is not true.  You can certainly continue playing the Java edition of game on Windows 10.  You will just have to download the game onto the new computer (and maybe manually move saves using a USB flash drive or some other means to get your save data onto the Windows 10 machine).

Comment: A long way to say "Yes, try it".

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Windows 10 does not require you to use its version.